# A conversation between 2 persons in two different languages

Tags: single-word-requests

If you've seen the first Star Wars trilogy (meaning Episodes 4 - 6), in the original Star Wars movie, Han Solo is in the cantina talking with Greedo (and yes, darnit, Han shot first! no shame in that, Greedo posed a mortal danger to him).  But each is speaking in his own language, Han in English (Empirish?) and Greedo in his native language.  Yet the conversation proceeded normally -- for a little while, at least.

I have a personal experience with this phenomenon, having once been in the US Army in the Netherlands attending a NATO class on how to maintain a particular kind of microwave radio, and for the lab portion of the class I was paired with a German soldier. It happened that we were both bilingual in English and German, and so rather than both of us using one or the other language, I proposed that we speak our native languages, and see how that would work -- both of us understood each other's language better than we spoke it.  So we did and it worked out really well.  I imagine that it sounded darned funny to some of the other US soldiers in the room who overheard our conversation (the class was taught in English, so non-US and -Brit soldiers had to have English as an additional language to attend).

Designating one's native language as A, and a second language as B, is there a word for this kind of conversation where the two participants speak their own language A while understanding in their language B?

Comment: Confusion? Cacophony? :p

Comment: Yeah, haha, but it isn't confusing to the two participants.

Comment: I do this nearly every day of my life with colleagues at work. It is not at all uncommon for us to be carrying out trilingual conversations.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, that's neat!  Are you in Switzerland?  I live deep in an English-speaking continent, there's no reason for anyone to know any other language (except once in awhile  Spanish is useful). I even have a hard time getting my German-born wife to speak German to me!

Comment: No, not Switzerland—Denmark. I just happen to work in a place that’s relatively evenly divided between Danes, Swedes, and Norwegians, all of which are mutually intelligible with just a bit of practice. (There are some Finns, too, but Finnish is _quite_ a different kettle of non-Indo-European fish, and nobody understands them much unless they switch to Swedish, which they usually do.)

Comment: See also the answers to a similar question on Linguistics SE: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34772/term-for-conversation-where-each-person-speaks-a-different-language-while-under

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may call it **bilingual dialogue** but it is an aspect of **[code-switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching)** as well.

> Multilinguals—speakers of more than one language—sometimes use elements of multiple languages when conversing with each other.

---

**Bonus:**

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BilingualDialogue

---

**Further reading:**

> [Article:](http://www.colorado.edu/ling/CRIL/Volume19_Issue1/paper_NILEP.pdf)
>   **“Code Switching” in Sociocultural Linguistics** - *Chad Nilep - University of Colorado, Boulder*
>
> ---
>
> [Book:](http://books.google.ca/books?id=jbWXpCQoWWoC&pg=PT153&lpg=PT153&dq=bilingual%20dialogue&source=bl&ots=W9UzM6wwIp&sig=9s4rPZ_CGBJQJ-tCpqlGiFL5kS8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V4QjU-XtMonG2wXBuYG4Dg&ved=0CGEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=bilingual%20dialogue&f=false) **Multidisciplinary Approaches to Code Switching** -
>    *edited by Ludmila Isurin, Donald Winford, Kees De Bot*
>
> Chapter 6 - Two speakers, one dialogue - An interactive alignment perspective on code-switching in bilingual speakers

Comment: Sounds good, but there may be an official linguistic term for it, for which I will hold out.  For a while anyway.  I read up on code-switching and "bilingual dialogue" doesn't seem to be a true aspect of code-switching.  Although I can see the attraction of saying it is.  Nice bonus!

Comment: code-switching is the linguistics term. You may check the real life section of the bonus link as well.

Comment: Yes, as I say, I see the attraction, but what I described involved no *switching*, per se.  That's a great link, by the way.

Comment: I don't think it's code-switching, but +1 for bilingual dialogue.

Comment: If you think from the perspective of the other person, you switch the whole language, even from the beginning. It may happen during the conversation as well. Added more sources.

Comment: OK, you convinced me.  :-)